# How do I automate the refresh of a dataset thats linked to a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a dataset that's been created via direct URL link to a google sheet. Teams will be updating the data in the sheet, and I would like to be able to schedule a daily refresh of the dataset, rather than myself manually clicking refresh in the UI. I haven't had any luck searching this online, has anyone been able to accomplish this?

I've been searching online but have not found anything that works, specific to datasets built via link to a sheet doc.

Answer (score 0):

If you created the table as a Google Sheet file format the connection is live. Any change in the document will automatically show up when you query the table in BigQuery.

[image]

Comment: Wow didn't even realize that, thank you! Problem didn't exist in the first place

Answer (score 0):

This problem doesn't exist - If you created the table as a Google Sheet file format the connection is live. Any change in the document will automatically show up when you query the table in BigQuery.